# welcome-file-list being ignored by server?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I am having problems trying to reconfigure the welcome page of a project I've joined recently.
Using JBoss 7 and Wildfly 10 to test the application, but both servers fail the same way.

I want to be able to access my webapp by using this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/MaisAcoes/
```

And I want this URL to display the "index.xhtml" page.

Problem is: the server always displays error 404 while trying to open "index.jsf" (as this page does not exist). It doesn't open the "index.xhtml" page.

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>MaisAcoes</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The index.xhtml page is located at the WebContent folder and deployed correctly... If I try to access the page directly (http://localhost:8081/MaisAcoes/index.xhtml), the page opens successfully.

What am I missing..?

Comment: Sure it isn't just the browser cache? Try in an incognito window.

Comment: @BalusC clearing the cache solved the problem! I tried to perform a full clean on the server, but I would never imagine that the problem was on the browser's cache. Thank you very much!

Comment: Typo web.xhtml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by member **BalusC** in the comments, this problem was solved by simply clearing the cache of my browser.

I have tried to perform a full clean in the servers (JBoss 7 and Wildfly 10), but this didn't work... Cleaning the browser's cached solved the issue and made the webapp load the right page.